# How can I make a Makefile file target depend on a different path?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I apologize for the ambiguous title, I couldn't think of a simple way to phrase it due to my lack of knowledge in GNU make.

I'm writing a simple Makefile for a small project, and I'm trying to enable it to generate individual objects by using their base name (without path) as the target:

```
$(BASE_OBJS) : %.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(OBJDIR) $(INCLUDES)                        
    @echo $(CC): [$(notdir $<)] '->' [$(notdir $@)]                          
    @$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

The problem is that the 'make' app obviously expects the target object to be present in the current folder, but it's actually found in the $(OBJDIR) subfolder. The causes those targets to unnecessarily rebuild.

Alternatively, this rule does check for the object's existence in the right place:

```
$(OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDES)       
    @echo $(CC): [$(notdir $<)] '->' [$(notdir $@)]                          
    @$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

But it can't be used for running things like 'make main.o', as $(OBJS) includes the full path of the objects, so it only allows things like 'make output/main.o'.

If it's a duplicate then I'm sorry, I was looking for a while and couldn't find a similar question.

For reference, these are the variable definitions:

```
BASE_SRC=$(notdir $(SOURCES))                                                    
BASE_OBJS = $(BASE_SRC:%.c=%.o)                                                  
OBJS = $(BASE_OBJS:%.o=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

Comment: "*and I'm trying to enable it to generate individual objects by using their base name (without path) as the target*" <- that's a conceptional mis-use of `make`. By all means, targets *should* be files, because this is how `make` works (and `make` determines from their timestamps whether these files must be rebuilt). You *can* have a few "*phony*" targets (typically `all`, `clean`, ...) but you really **don't** want your intermediary object files created through a *phony* target, it would mean to rebuild them *each time you run make*, even if nothing changed.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that the targets would be rebuilt every time, I posted my question in order to know if there's a way to prevent it from happening.

About misuse: That was my first thought, but then I recalled that the Linux kernel build system for example allows building *.dtb files by their name from the main folder, without rebuilding unnecessarily, and I thought it was possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main set of targets and prerequisites must use the full path, because that's how make works.  So you must have something like:

```
$(OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(INCLUDES)       
        @echo $(CC): [$(notdir $<)] '->' [$(notdir $@)]                          
        @$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

Now if *in addition* you want to be able to run a simple `make foo.o`, then to do that you should define extra "alias" targets for the real targets.  These rules only exist for the short-hand, they don't actually do anything.  Something like:

```
$(BASE_OBJS) : %.o : $(OBJDIR)/%.o
```